# Drawing images onto Pygame's background or screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a game with `pygame` which involves two player-controlled tanks which go around a brick map with their own health bars and shoot each other with one kind of bullet. From what I can tell, everything else is working, but I am having trouble determining which surface to draw the bricks, tanks, and bullets on: the "background" or the "screen" (the bricks do not change during the game, only the tanks and bullets). I tried drawing everything but the health bars on the background, but that just resulted in a black screen which only displayed the health bars. I then drew everything directly onto the screen and that displays everything correctly at first, but when the tanks move around, the screen doesn't refresh (I get many many tank images overlapping each other as the tank moves) and the bullets do not fire properly as a result. The code is below but the `main()` method is at the very bottom and that is what is causing errors. The "effects.py" file that is imported at the very top contains just the bullets and "booms" and "bombs" classes which are just special effects but aren't used so far in the main() method so they can be ignored.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import pygame, os, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import effects
from effects import *
import math
GRAD = math.pi / 180

class Brick(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, image, top, bottom, right, left, bricks):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.rect = image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.image = image
        self.pos = pos
        self.top = top
        self.bottom = bottom
        self.right = right
        self.left = left
        self.health = 30
        bricks.add(self)


class City(object):

    def __init__(self, bricks, level):

        self.level = level

        self.city =  self.level.convert_alpha()  

        self.brick = pygame.image.load("brick.png").convert_alpha()
        self.bricks = bricks

        self.x = self.y = 0
        collidable = (255, 0, 0, 255)
        self.height = self.city.get_height()
        self.width = self.city.get_width()
        self.vehicle_pos = (0,0)

        while self.y < self.height:
            color = self.city.get_at((self.x, self.y))
            collidable =  (255, 0, 0, 255), (0,0,0,255)
            top = False
            bottom = False
            right = False
            left = False
            if color in collidable:
                self.bricks.add(Brick((self.x*30, self.y*30), self.brick, top, bottom, right, left, self.bricks))
                print ("brick added!")
                print (self.x, self.y)


            self.x += 1

            if self.x >= self.width:
                self.x = 0
                self.y += 1

    def get_size(self):
        return [self.city.get_size()[0]*30, self.city.get_size()[1]*30]


class Tank(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    book = {} # a book of tanks to store all tanks
    number = 0 # each tank gets his own number

    firekey = (pygame.K_SPACE, pygame.K_RETURN)
    forwardkey = (pygame.K_w, pygame.K_i)
    backwardkey = (pygame.K_s, pygame.K_k)
    tankLeftkey = (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_j)
    tankRightkey = (pygame.K_d, pygame.K_l)

    color = ((200,200,0), (0,0,200))

    def __init__(self, pos, angle, health):
        self.number = Tank.number
        Tank.number += 1
        Tank.book[self.number] = self
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.tank_pic = pygame.image.load("tank.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.tank_pic
        self.image_type = self.tank_pic
        self.tank1_pic = pygame.image.load("tank1.png").convert_alpha()
        self._image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.rect.move(pos)
        self.tankAngle = angle # tank facing

        #---handles controls---#

        self.firekey = Tank.firekey[self.number] # main gun
        self.forwardkey = Tank.forwardkey[self.number] # move tank
        self.backwardkey = Tank.backwardkey[self.number] # reverse tank
        self.tankLeftkey = Tank.tankLeftkey[self.number] # rotate tank
        self.tankRightkey = Tank.tankRightkey[self.number] # rotat tank


        self.health = health
        self.alive = True
        self.speed = 5
        self.angle = angle
        self.timer = 3
        self.timerstart = 0
        self.x, self.y = self.rect.center
        self.bullet_s = pygame.mixer.Sound("bullet.wav")
        self.bullet_s.set_volume(.25)

    def rotate(self):
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self._image, self.angle, 1.0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center)

    def update(self, keys, bricks, bullets, booms, bombs):
        self.bricks = bricks
        self.t = True
        self._rect = Rect(self.rect)
        self._rect.center = self.x, self.y
        self.rotate()
        turn_speed = 3


        pressedkeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressedkeys[self.forwardkey]:
            self.x += sin(radians(self.angle))*-self.speed
            self.y += cos(radians(self.angle))*-self.speed
        if pressedkeys[self.backwardkey]:
            self.x += sin(radians(self.angle))*self.speed
            self.y += cos(radians(self.angle))*self.speed
        if pressedkeys[self.tankLeftkey]:
            self.angle += turn_speed
        if pressedkeys[self.tankRightkey]:
            self.angle -= turn_speed
        if keys[self.firekey]:
            if self.timer >= 3:
                self.timer = self.timerstart
                self.b_size = "small"
                bullets.add(Bullet(self.rect.center, self.angle, self.b_size, "vehicle"))
                self.bullet_s.play()

        if self.timer < 3:
            self.timer += 1

        if self.angle > 360:
            self.angle = self.angle-360
        if self.angle <0:
            self.angle = self.angle+360

        self.rect.center = self.x, self.y

        x = self.rect.centerx
        y = self.rect.centery
        _x = self._rect.centerx
        _y = self._rect.centery
        for b in bricks:
            if self.rect.colliderect(b.rect):
                if _x+21 <= b.rect.left and x+21 > b.rect.left:
                    if b.left == True:
                        self.x = b.rect.left-21
                if _x-21 >= b.rect.right and x-21 < b.rect.right:
                    if b.right == True:
                        self.x = b.rect.right+21
                if _y+21 <= b.rect.top and y+21 > b.rect.top:
                    if b.top == True:
                        self.y = b.rect.top-21
                if _y-21 >= b.rect.bottom and y-21 < b.rect.bottom:
                    if b.bottom == True:
                        self.y = b.rect.bottom+21

        for b in bullets:
            if self.rect.colliderect(b.rect):
                b_size = b.get_size()
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill(b)
                if b_size == "small":
                    booms.add(Boom(b.rect.center, "small"))
                    self.health -= 1
                if b_size == "big":
                    booms.add(Boom(b.rect.center, "big"))
                    self.health -=5

        for b in bombs:
            if self.rect.colliderect(b.rect) and b.timer == 20:
                self.health -=5

        if self.health <= 0:
            booms.add(Boom(self.rect.center, "huge"))
            self.alive = False
            self.health = 0
        '''if self.image_type == self.tank_pic:
            self.image = self.tank1_pic
            self.image_type = self.tank1_pic
            print "switch 1"
        if self.image_type == self.tank1_pic:
            self.image = self.tank_pic
            self.image_type = self.tank_pic
            print "switch 2"'''

class Turret(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, angle, follow):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("turret.png").convert_alpha()
        self.timer = 40
        self.timer_start = self.timer
        self.size = "big"
        self.bang_s = pygame.mixer.Sound("bang.wav")
        self.speed = 3
        self.bang_s.set_volume(1.0)
        self._image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.rect.move(pos)
        self.angle = angle
        self.timer = 40
        self.wait_timer = 5
        self.timer_restart = 0
        self.x, self.y = self.rect.center
        self.follow = follow

    def rotate(self):
        center = self._rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self._image, self.angle, 1.0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center)

    def update(self, pos, mx, my, keys, booms, tank_angle, bricks, background, city):
        self.background = background
        self.city_size = city
        self.t = True
        self.bricks = bricks
        self.end = None
        self._rect = Rect(self.rect)
        self._rect.center = pos
        self.tank_angle = tank_angle
        t_x, t_y = self.rect.center


        if keys[K_m]:
            if self.wait_timer >= 5:
                self.follow = not self.follow
                self.wait_timer = self.timer_restart
        if self.follow:
            self.mouse_angle = math.atan2(xd, yd)*(180/math.pi)+180 #used atan2(x,y) instead of atan2(y,x). Sprite was origanly drawn along the y axis, gave better results
            if self.angle < self.mouse_angle:
                if math.fabs(self.angle - self.mouse_angle) < 180:
                    self.angle +=self.speed
                else:
                    self.angle -=self.speed
            else:
                if math.fabs(self.angle - self.mouse_angle) < 180:
                    self.angle -=self.speed
                else:
                    self.angle +=self.speed
            if math.fabs(self.angle - self.mouse_angle) < self.speed+.5:
                self.angle = self.mouse_angle

        if not self.follow:
            if self.angle != self.tank_angle:
                if self.angle < self.tank_angle:
                    if math.fabs(self.angle - self.tank_angle) < 180:
                        self.angle +=self.speed
                    else:
                        self.angle -=self.speed
                else:
                    if math.fabs(self.angle - self.tank_angle) < 180:
                        self.angle -=self.speed
                    else:
                        self.angle +=self.speed
                if math.fabs(self.angle - self.tank_angle) < self.speed+.5:
                    self.angle = self.tank_angle
            else:
                self.angle = self.tank_angle

        self.rotate()
        if self.angle > 360:
            self.angle = self.angle-360
        if self.angle <0:
            self.angle = self.angle+360
        if self.wait_timer < 5:
            self.wait_timer += 1



# ---------- END OF CLASSES ---------- #


def main():

    pygame.init()
    version = "Tank Wars 2.0"
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1170, 510),0,32)
    n = 1
    size = screen.get_size()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    map_ = pygame.image.load("c2.png")
    health = 40
    health_full = health

    bricks= pygame.sprite.Group()
    bricks_des = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bricks_non = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    booms = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bombers = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bombs = pygame.sprite.Group()
    tanks = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allgroup = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()


    #assign default groups to each sprite class
    #Tank.groups = tanks, allgroup
    #Turret.groups = allgroup
    #Bullet.groups = bullets, allgroup

    city = City(bricks, map_)
    city_size = city.get_size()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    timer = 0
    chance = None
    score = 0

    player1 = Tank((150, 250), 360, 40)
    tanks.add(player1)
    player2 = Tank((1100, 250), 360, 40)
    tanks.add(player2)
    player1_turret = Turret((150, 250), 360, False)
    player2_turret = Turret((1100, 250), 360, False)


    background = pygame.Surface((city_size), 0, 32)
    city.bricks.draw(screen)


    font4 = pygame.font.Font("7theb.ttf", 13)
    font5 = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier New", 16, bold=True)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    return

        clock.tick(24)
        time_passed = clock.tick()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        background.fill((87, 87, 87))

        if player1.alive == True:
            player1.update(keys, bricks, bullets, booms, bombs)
            player1_turret.update(player1.rect.center, m_x, m_y, keys, booms, 360, bricks, background, city_size)
            screen.blit(player1.image, player1.rect)
            screen.blit(player1_turret.image, player1_turret.rect)
        if player2.alive == True:
            player2.update(keys, bricks, bullets, booms, bombs)
            player2_turret.update(player2.rect.center, m_x, m_y, keys, booms, 360, bricks, background, city_size)
            screen.blit(player2.image, player2.rect)
            screen.blit(player2_turret.image, player2_turret.rect)

        bullets.update(bricks, booms)
        bombs.update(booms, player1)
        bombs.update(booms, player2)
        booms.update(background)  


        bombs.draw(screen)
        bullets.draw(screen)
        bombers.draw(screen)


        healthshow = font4.render('Health ', False, (255,255,255))

        #---Player 1 Healthbar---#

        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, ((player1.health*255)/health_full),0), (90, 20, 10, 13))
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, ((player1.health*255)/health_full),0), (92+(100*(float(player1.health)/float(health_full))), 20, 10, 13))
        screen.fill((255,((player1.health*255)/health_full),0),(96,20,(100*(float(player1.health)/float(health_full))), 13))
        screen.blit(healthshow, (5, 20))

        #---Player 2 Healthbar---#

        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, ((player2.health*255)/health_full),0), (90, 20, 10, 13))
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, ((player2.health*255)/health_full),0), (92+(100*(float(player2.health)/float(health_full))), 20, 10, 13))
        screen.fill((255,((player2.health*255)/health_full),0),(96,20,(100*(float(player2.health)/float(health_full))), 13))
        screen.blit(healthshow, (500, 20))


        allgroup.clear(screen, background)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: It only means you either don't refresh the tank which was drawn in the last frame, or that for some reason you draw all of the tanks together. As the first one is probably the problem, after flipping the display try `pygame.display.update(tank.rect)` where `tank` is the class of the tank whose images are overlapping. By the way, notice that when having problem you could always import the debugger (`gdb`).

Comment: I draw the tanks separately like this for each player:

screen.blit(player1.image, player1.rect)
screen.blit(player1_turret.image, player1_turret.rect)

I tried doing what you suggested but it didn't fix the problem of hundreds of tank images being drawn and not refreshed. Is there another possible problem? Also, when I try:

import gdb

it doesn't work - do I have to download something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make a global `screen` variable (instead of being wrapped inside a function, and generate a single city image, with the bricks added to it. Since those are all the components that do not change, this can be blitted to the screen every time the frame is refreshed.

After that, on each frame, the tank (with health bar and other stuff) and bullets can be blitted directly to the `screen` variable.

It is probably simplest to just do `pygame.display.flip()` after all of the blitting is done, but keeping an array of `pygame.Rects` representing blit positions and *then* keeping the old blit `Rects` and then doing something like:

```
old_rects = current_rects
current_rects = []
#make blits, collect Rects in current_rects
pygame.display.update(current_rects + old_rects)
```

This way, `pygame.display.update()` can be used (since it is more efficient), and there won't be problems with no refreshing.

I hope this works and that you can implement something like this.